# Remove Marker Google map API v2 -Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker, removeall

I draw one Marker

**Example:**

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(10, 10));
```

How to satisfy a given condition will be deleted Marker

Comment: Marker drawing also need new conditions are drawn

Comment: ex : if (condition) 
{
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(10, 10));
}
if (condition) {
marker.remove;
}

Answer (score 0):

Using the Google Maps API you can use the method `remove()`. Say you added a marker `Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(10, 10));`

You could remove the marker using: `marker.remove();`

Comment: Marker drawing also need new conditions are drawn

Comment: ex : if (condition) 
{
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(10, 10));
}
if (condition) {
marker.remove;
}